# What determines if a hibernate session is available outside of @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate

My Spring app uses `@org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` throughout to open up transactions. In an effort to drop unnecessary overhead relating to transactions, I've started removing some of these annotations in areas of the app where a transaction is not required.

In doing so, I've noticed that `@Controller` classes which have had the `@Transactional` annotation removed (at the class level or method level) are still able to use `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()`. However, when I removed the `@Transactional` annotation from a `@Service` (specifically, an implementation of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService`) and tried to call `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()`, I received the following:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.xxx.datasource.AbstractDAO.getSession(AbstractDAO.java:35)
    at com.xxx.datasource.UserDAO.getLoginUser(UserDAO.java:209)
    at com.xxx.datasource.UserDAO.getLoginUser(UserDAO.java:199)
    at com.xxx.spring.userdetails.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:24)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:102)
    ... 49 more
```

Why is this happening / what determines if `SessionFactory#getCurrentSession()` will return a session or throw an exception?

(Spring 4.1.9 and Hibernate 4.3.11)

Comment: Spring keeps the hibernate session opened for the web to use using a filter.  Please see [http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewFilter.html] . But thuis is only for the Views and in the server side you need to have your own transaction annotation markers to manage transaction as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method call `SesssionFactory.getCurrentSession()` in a method/class not annotatated with `@Transactional` will lead to exception as `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive()` will return false. It return false because @Transaction aspect haven't been executed thus transaction synchronization remains inactive for the current thread. had it get executed it would have Activated transaction synchronization for the current thread. 
Method to look : `TransactionSynchronizationManager.initSynchronization` and `TransactionSynchronizationManager.isSynchronizationActive`

And as you mentioned your @Controller classes are working fine , that may be because either they are not performing any dao operation or the layer ahead on controller is taking care of transaction.

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked at this myself beforehand, but I can now confirm that ` OpenSessionInViewInterceptor` is culpable. I was under the impression that this pattern was opening the session *only once the request reached the view layer*; but infact, due to it being a spring interceptor, it opens it up in the interceptor's `preHandle` phase, before the controller method is hit.